# How to convert synthetic control dataset in RDD [ Vector ] for K-Means algorithm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am trying to convert the "Synthetic Control Chart Time Series Data Set" available in Uci Machine Learning.

The appearance of the dataset is the next..

```
28.7812 34.4632 31.3381 31.2834 28.9207 33.7596 25.3969 27.7849 35.2479 27.1159 32.8717 29.2171 36.0253 32.337  34.5249 32.8717 34.1173 26.5235 27.6623 26.3693 25.7744 29.27   30.7326 29.5054 33.0292 25.04   28.9167 24.3437 26.1203 34.9424 25.0293 26.6311 35.6541 28.4353 29.1495 28.1584 26.1927 33.3182 30.9772 27.0443 35.5344 26.2353 28.9964 32.0036 31.0558 34.2553 28.0721 28.9402 35.4973 29.747  31.4333 24.5556 33.7431 25.0466 34.9318 34.9879 32.4721 33.3759 25.4652 25.8717
24.8923 25.741  27.5532 32.8217 27.8789 31.5926 31.4861 35.5469 27.9516 31.6595 27.5415 31.1887 27.4867 31.391  27.811  24.488  27.5918 35.6273 35.4102 31.4167 30.7447 24.1311 35.1422 30.4719 31.9874 33.6615 25.5511 30.4686 33.6472 25.0701 34.0765 32.5981 28.3038 26.1471 26.9414 31.5203 33.1089 24.1491 28.5157 25.7906 35.9519 26.5301 24.8578 25.9562 32.8357 28.5322 26.3458 30.6213 28.9861 29.4047 32.5577 31.0205 26.6418 28.4331 33.6564 26.4244 28.4661 34.2484 32.1005 26.691
31.3987 30.6316 26.3983 24.2905 27.8613 28.5491 24.9717 32.4358 25.2239 27.3068 31.8387 27.2587 28.2572 26.5819 24.0455 35.0625 31.5717 32.5614 31.0308 34.1202 26.9337 31.4781 35.0173 32.3851 24.3323 30.2001 31.2452 26.6814 31.5137 28.8778 27.3086 24.246  26.9631 25.2919 31.6114 24.7131 27.4809 24.2075 26.8059 35.1253 32.6293 31.0561 26.3583 28.0861 31.4391 27.3057 29.6082 35.9725 34.1444 27.1717 33.6318 26.5966 25.5387 32.5434 25.5772 29.9897 31.351  33.9002 29.5446 29.343
```

The data is stored in an ASCII file, 600 rows, 60 columns, with a single chart per line. The numbers of each block are separated by a space, and each block is separated by a line break. I have to convert all the rows with 60 numbers for row and stored it in RDD [ Vector ]. All positions on a vector must have 60 numbers. The RDD [ Vector ] would have the following appearance...

```
[28.7812 34.4632 31.3381 31.2834 28.9207 33.7596 25.3969 27.7849 35.2479 27.1159 32.8717 29.2171 36.0253 32.337  34.5249 32.8717 34.1173 26.5235 27.6623 26.3693 25.7744 29.27   30.7326 29.5054 33.0292 25.04   28.9167 24.3437 26.1203 34.9424 25.0293 26.6311 35.6541 28.4353 29.1495 28.1584 26.1927 33.3182 30.9772 27.0443 35.5344 26.2353 28.9964 32.0036 31.0558 34.2553 28.0721 28.9402 35.4973 29.747  31.4333 24.5556 33.7431 25.0466 34.9318 34.9879 32.4721 33.3759 25.4652 25.8717]
[24.8923 25.741  27.5532 32.8217 27.8789 31.5926 31.4861 35.5469 27.9516 31.6595 27.5415 31.1887 27.4867 31.391  27.811  24.488  27.5918 35.6273 35.4102 31.4167 30.7447 24.1311 35.1422 30.4719 31.9874 33.6615 25.5511 30.4686 33.6472 25.0701 34.0765 32.5981 28.3038 26.1471 26.9414 31.5203 33.1089 24.1491 28.5157 25.7906 35.9519 26.5301 24.8578 25.9562 32.8357 28.5322 26.3458 30.6213 28.9861 29.4047 32.5577 31.0205 26.6418 28.4331 33.6564 26.4244 28.4661 34.2484 32.1005 26.691]
```

I am trying to convert the data, but I have one exception. The code is this...

```
val data = sc.textFile("/home/david/Desktop/synthetic.txt")
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split("\n").map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

When I run the K-Means algorithm I have one exception..

```
val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
```

This is the exception

```
16/06/07 19:56:06 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)

java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1020)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at org.test.spark.RunKMeans$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RunKMeans.scala:22)
    at org.test.spark.RunKMeans$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RunKMeans.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.test.spark.RunKMeans$$anonfun$1.apply(RunKMeans.scala:22)
    at org.test.spark.RunKMeans$$anonfun$1.apply(RunKMeans.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are splitting by \n (new line), you are suppose to split by space, and convert each element to a Double before you can Dense it into a Mllib Vector.

So change the s.split("\n") to s.split(" ") or use \s instead

=========EDIT=========

since you are splitting on multiple spaces, you should use:

```
 split("\\s+")
```

which will split on single, and multiple spaces.

Comment: I edit my code but now I have other exception- java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.

Comment: do you have a trailing space in your data? Also, does every line contain the same number of Doubles?

Comment: @DavidRebeGarcia Then show us your edited code, We can't guess what changes you made. And as GameOfThrows says, it's probably an empty space. You have several numbers with more than one space between them so check your split deals with that.

Comment: `val data = sc.textFile("/home/david/Desktop/synthetic.txt")            val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(" ").map(_.toDouble))).cache()`. The dataset composed by 600 blocks with 60 numbers each block. Each block is separated by a line break to others block, but the numbers in the block are separated by one or more spaces . Sometimes , the number has more than one space for to all the numbers are the same size .

Comment: It's already working. Here is the full code execution.                                `import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}`
`import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors`
`val data = sc.textFile("/home/david/Desktop/synthetic.txt")`
`val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split("\\s+").map(_.toDouble))).cache()`

// Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
`val numClusters = 2`
`val numIterations = 20`
`val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)`. Thank you very much @GameOfThrows.

Comment: Sorry @GameOfThrows but I tried KMeans with other dataset. When I execute your command I have this exception. `16/06/07 17:49:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`

Comment: @DavidRebeGarcia It means there is a empty number in your set - I do not know what it is since I do not see the dataset, here are a few things you need to check - 1, is there a trailing space in each line? 2, read only the first line of your dataset and output it as a Array[Double] and see if it works. 3, read the last 10 lines of your dataset and output it as a Array[Double] and see if it works. If all of the above does not solve the problem, you should consider parsing your data through a case class and discard data lines where there are less than 60 columns

Comment: @GameOfThrows the dataset has 600 lines with 60 columns per line. I think that the problem is the space between the numbers, but I am not sure. I will try with your explanations.

Comment: if you are using `split("\\s+")` then it does not care how many spaces there are between the numbers.

Comment: @GameOfThrows when I read the data it works well, the problem is when I parse the data. This is the code
      `val data = sc.textFile("/home/david/Desktop/Datos Entrada/syntheticBlancos.txt")` Here it prints the first two lines, but the data do not parse correctly..
      `data.take(2).foreach(println)`
      `val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split("\\s+").map(_.toDouble))).cache()`
      `val numClusters = 2 `
     `val numIterations = 20 `
      `val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)`

Comment: I edit the file. Now the file has 600 lines with 60 numbers each line. The numbers are separated by one space. When I prints the two first lines, each line has 60 numbers separated by one space, but I do not know  what have I do to transform this line in double. The exception is the same. What can I do?

Comment: you did not understand me at all - parse your data by doing data.take(2).split("\\s+").map(_.toDouble) - see if it breaks, if it does, your data is breaking the splitting rule - in this case post the exact 2 lines of your txt file so I can check and tell you what when wrong. - Using the ones you currently posted does not result in any errors at my end, so I cannot recreate what you've done.

Comment: @GameOfThrows when I execute your code the program works well, but only with two lines. The dataset is avaliable at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/synthetic_control-mld/synthetic_control.data

Comment: When I try the following code val data = sc.textFile("/home/david/Desktop/Datos Entrada/synthetic.txt")`` val parsedData = dataPrueba.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split("\\s+").map(_.toDouble))).cache() val dataPrueba = parsedData.take(600), after executing this code dataPrueba has the 600 vectors with the data, but when I execute the KMeans I have the exception

Comment: @DavidRebeGarcia also, do a saveAsTextFile on parsedData and see if there are empty numbers - you can just open it in text editor and use the find function and look for ",," or ", ,"

Comment: When I try to change the data appears this exception. `Description Resource Path Location Type
value replaceAll is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] RunKMeans.scala /spark/src/main/scala/org/test/spark line 20 Scala Problem`

Comment: sorry, do data.map( _.replaceAll("""(?m)\s+$""", ""))